# I am new to React and building a basic application using it

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have followed the steps mentioned in Tutorials Point to build the React. NPM start was also successful. But on running the application on CHROME, i am getting the below exception.

> ```
> /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap /******/ function hotDisposeChunk(chunkId) { /******/ delete
> ```
>
> installedChunks[chunkId]; /******/ } /******/ var
>   parentHotUpdateCallback = this["webpackHotUpdate"]; /******/
>   this["webpackHotUpdate"] = /******/ function
>   webpackHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules) { //
>   eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars /******/ hotAddUpdateChunk(chunkId,
>   moreModules); /******/ if(parentHotUpdateCallback)
>   parentHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules); /******/ } ; /******/
>   /******/ function hotDownloadUpdateChunk(chunkId) { //
>   eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars /******/ var head =
>   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; /******/ var script =
>   document.createElement("script"); /******/ script.type =
>   "text/javascript"; /******/ script.charset = "utf-8"; /******/
>   script.src = **webpack_require**.p + "" + chunkId + "." +
>   hotCurrentHash + ".hot-update.js"; /******/ head.appendChild(script);
>   /******/ } /******/ /******/ function hotDownloadManifest() { //
>   eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars /******/ return new
>   Promise(function(resolve, reject) { /******/ if(typeof XMLHttpRequest
>   === "undefined") /******/ return reject(new Error("No browser support")); /******/ try { /******/ var request = new
>   XMLHttpRequest(); /******/ var requestPath = **webpack_require**.p +
>   "" + hotCurrentHash + ".hot-update.json"; /******/ request.open("GET",
>   requestPath, true); /******/ request.timeout = 10000; /******/
>   request.send(null); /******/ } catch(err) { /******/ return
>   reject(err); /******/ } /******/ request.onreadystatechange =
>   function() { /******/ if(request.readyState !== 4) return; /******/
>   if(request.status === 0) { /******/ // timeout /******/ reject(new
>   Error("Manifest request to " + requestPath + " timed out.")); /******/
>   } else if(request.status === 404) { /******/ // no update available
>   /******/ resolve(); /******/ } else if(request.status !== 200 &&
>   request.status !== 304) { /******/ // other failure /******/
>   reject(new Error("Manifest request to " + requestPath + " failed."));
>   /******/ } else { /******/ // success /******/ try { /******/ var
>   update = JSON.parse(request.responseText); /******/ } catch(e) {
>   /******/ reject(e); /******/ return; /******/ } /******/
>   resolve(update); /******/ } /******/ }; /******/ }); /******/ }
>   /******/ /******/ /******/ /******/ var hotApplyOnUpdate = true;
>   /******/ var hotCurrentHash = "b2ee6a68403ad9971596"; //
>   eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars /******/ var hotCurrentModuleData =
>   {}; /******/ var hotMainModule = true; // eslint-disable-line
>   no-unused-vars /******/ var hotCurrentParents = []; //
>   eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars /******/ var hotCurrentParentsTemp
>   = []; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars /******/ /******/ function hotCreateRequire(moduleId) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
>   /******/ var me = installedModules[moduleId]; /******/ if(!me) return
>   **webpack_require**; /******/ var fn = function(request) { /******/ if(me.hot.active) { /******/ if(installedModules[request]) { /******/
>   if(installedModules[request].parents.indexOf(moduleId) < 0) /******/
>   installedModules[request].parents.push(moduleId); /******/ } else
>   hotCurrentParents = [moduleId]; /******/
>   if(me.children.indexOf(request) < 0) /******/
>   me.children.push(request); /******/ } else { /******/
>   console.warn("[HMR] unexpected require(" + request + ") from disposed
>   module " + moduleId); /******/ hotCurrentParents = []; /******/ }
>   /******/ hotMainModule = false; /******/ return
>   **webpack_require**(request); /******/ }; /******/ var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) { /******/ return { /******/
>   configurable: true, /******/ enumerable: true, /******/ get:
>   function() { /******/ return **webpack_require**[name]; /******/ },
>   /******/ set: function(value) { /******/ **webpack_require**[name] =
>   value; /******/ } /******/ }; /******/ }; /******/ for(var name in
>   **webpack_require**) { /******/ if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(**webpack_require**, name)) {
>   /******/ Object.defineProperty(fn, name, ObjectFactory(name));
>   /******/ } /******/ } /******/ Object.defineProperty(fn, "e", {
>   /******/ enumerable: true, /******/ value: function(chunkId) {
>   /******/ if(hotStatus === "ready") /******/ hotSetStatus("prepare");
>   /******/ hotChunksLoading++; /******/ return
>   **webpack_require**.e(chunkId).then(finishChunkLoading, function(err) { /******/ finishChunkLoading(); /******/ throw err; /******/ });
>   /******/ /******/ function finishChunkLoading() { /******/
>   hotChunksLoading--; /******/ if(hotStatus === "prepare") { /******/
>   if(!hotWaitingFilesMap[chunkId]) { /******/
>   hotEnsureUpdateChunk(chunkId); /******/ } /******/ if(hotChunksLoading
>   === 0 && hotWaitingFiles === 0) { /******/ hotUpdateDownloaded(); /******/ } /******/ } /******/ } /******/ } /******/ }); /******/
>   return fn; /******/ } /******/ /******/ function
>   hotCreateModule(moduleId) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
>   /******/ var hot = { /******/ // private stuff /******/
>   _acceptedDependencies: {}, /******/ _declinedDependencies: {}, /******/ _selfAccepted: false, /******/ _selfDeclined: false, /******/
>   _disposeHandlers: [], /******/ _main: hotMainModule, /******/ /******/ // Module API /******/ active: true, /******/

Below is my Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactprgrams",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

Below is my Webpack.config.js:

var config={

```
entry: './src/main.jsx',
output: {
    path:'/',
    filename:'index.html'
},
devServer: {

    inline: true,
    port: 8000

},

module:{
    loaders:[{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
}
```

}
module.exports = config;

I have tried with different versions of webpack and webpack-dev-server. But could not resolve the issue. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Format your code plz

Comment: Format the code in sense

Answer (score 0):

Just try and fix your package.json as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server"
}
```

And run the following in your terminal/console:

```
npm run start:dev
```

For more information on how to use & configure webpack take a look [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server)

Comment: I did as you said but still i am facing the same issue. Server startup is succesfull